# Pegar apenas o primeiro nome dentro de uma consulta SQL

Tags: sql, query, return, convenções-de-nome

Como faço para pegar apenas o primeiro nome de uma coluna de nomes completos, utilizando uma consulta SQL?

Eu usei o seguinte código:

```
cliente_documento AS "CPF",
SUBSTRING (cliente_nome , 1, CHARINDEX(' ', cliente_nome, 1) - 1) as "NOME",
cliente_email as "EMAIL",
cliente_telefone1 as "TELEFONE",
Valido_Telefone1, Valido_Email
From tb_customers_go
WHERE cliente_documento in (select cliente_documento from tb_serviços_go
where cliente_documento not 
in (select replace(replace(cli_cpf_cnpj, '.', ''), '-', '') from tb_quiver) 
and convert(int, convert(varchar, nf_data_emissao, 112)) > 20220501)
```

No entanto, esse código não está retornando o primeiro nome.

Como faço para retornar?

Comment: Tenta `SUBSTRING_INDEX(cliente_nome , ' ', 1)`

Comment: Eu tentei, mas aparece o seguinte erro:  "Error saving the Query field.'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: Que banco está utilizando?

Comment: Então o sistema utiliza uma linguagem própria que é o SOQL

Comment: Pela doc parece não ter estas functions ...   https://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/text.html# ..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154279/salesforce-soql-string-functions-not-working-left-substitute-etc

Comment: Quem fornece este Banco ?

Comment: É o SalesForce, mas eu consegui resolver esse problema, usei 
left(cliente_nome, charindex(' ', cliente_nome)) as "NOME",.